# Cannot get expected result for Spring4D cryptography examples

Tags: delphi, hash, cryptography, spring4d

The Spring4D library has cryptography classes, however I cannot get them to work as expected. I'm probably using them incorrectly, however lack of any examples makes it difficult.

For example on the website https://quickhash.com/hash-sha256-online, I can hash the word "test" to generate the following hash:

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Using the Spring4D library, the following code produces a different hash:

```
CreateSHA256.ComputeHash('test').ToString;
```

results in:

```
9EFEA1AEAC9EDA04A892885A65FDAE0E6D9BE8C9FC96DA76D31B929262E12B1D
```

Upper/lower case aside, it is a different hash altogether. I know must be doing something wrong, but again there's no examples of use so I'm stuck on how to do this.

Comment: It's kind of tragic that this library lulls you into believing that you can hash text. You hash binary. Presumably the two variants encode the text with different encodings. Do yourself a favour and be explicit. Encode to UTF8 bytes and hash that.

Comment: I've changed the title as it is off topic to ask for examples on StackOverflow. You *didn't* but the title suggested that you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashing algorithms operate on binary data, typically represented using byte arrays.

Unfortunately, both of the resources you have used offer the ability to hash text. In order to hash text, you first need to convert from text to binary. To do so requires a choice of encoding. And neither method makes it clear what that choice is.

When I use this Delphi code:

```
LowerCase(CreateSHA256.ComputeHash(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('test')).ToString)
```

I get the same hash as appears in your question.

I urge you never to attempt to encrypt/hash text and instead regard these operations as operating on binary. Always use an explicit encoding and then encrypt/hash the array of bytes that the encoding produced.

I've picked the UTF-8 encoding here, because it is a full Unicode encoding, and tends to be efficient in terms of space. However, I don't think your online encoder uses UTF-8. In fact I've no idea what encoding it uses, it is unclear on the matter. This is of course the same old issue of text being different from binary.

In my opinion it is a design flaw of the Delphi library that you use that it allows you to hash text without an explicit choice of encoding. If this library must offer a function that hashes text, then it should require the caller to supply an extra `TEncoding` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There is no conversion going on internally so it hashes the UnicodeString which is at least 2 bytes per character.

If you want the same result as on the page you have to use UTF8Encode or directly pass as AnsiString.

However I tried some strings that contained different unicode characters and the page returned a different result. So I am not quite sure how they treat the strings there. I guess it's a codepage thing.

Edit: If you use this page http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator it generates the same hash as TSHA256 with UTF8Encode.

Comment: Delphi strings are encoding with UTF-16 rather than UCS2

Comment: as part of Spring4D, you might care to clarify this part of the library so that callers have to be explicit about how the text is encoded before it is hashed.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this myself. The documentation really should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of string are you using? Do you use AnsiString or WideString (Unicode string). Delphi 2009 and Newer are using WideString by default.

Why is string type inportant? All hasging algorithm operates on raw bytes data so it is omportant if each character of your string is stored in one Byte of memory (AnsiString) or multiple Bytes of memory (WideString).

Comment: Incorrect. Unicode Delphi makes `string` an alias to `UnicodeString` which is quite different from `WideString`.